# Archive history without exiting the shell

Tags: bash, zsh, command-history

I just realised that a workflow I've been using for years, doesn't do what it is supposed to do. Since I haven't realised that for such a long time, you might think it's not worth putting much effort into it, but it turns out that right now, it  has become somewhat important.

What am I talking about? Okay, I have `tmux` running with several sessions and each session has different windows and so on. Working like that is wonderful. There's one downside to it, though. When the server gets restarted, for whatever resason, it closes all my sessions. Fair enough, cannot be avoided and doesn't happen often. However, the annoying part is, that all my `zsh` or `bash` `history` is gone as well. This is a problem. I rely on my history, maybe far too much.

I was circumventing this problem by hitting `fc -W` (in `zsh`) every now and then. I thought this would append history that is in the memory and I would then only lose the part between my last invocation of `fc -W` and the restart of the server. But that's not what it does. If I use `fc -W` in one window, then `fc -W` in another one, the history from the first window would be overwritten by the history from the second window. I would need to use `fc -R` first, but this would duplicate the whole history... basically I was misusing the `fc` command the whole time.

Here's the question: How can I make sure to not lose any of my history when I'm in `tmux` and there is a sudden power cut? Note:

- I use infinite history, in case that matters.
- Losing some of the history is ok, i.e. if I have to invoke a command by hand (or in a cronjob) and I lose the part of the history since the command has last been run, that's fine.
- Exiting the terminal and open up new one is not the solution.
- **I don't want to store my commands directly to the history, since this mixes up different histories.**
- Solutions for both `bash` and `zsh` are welcome. `zsh` is preferred.

Edit: Highlight the part that everyone seems to misunderstand.

Comment: You need to set HISTFILE independently for each shell process, but using an algorithm that means you get the same filename when you restart a session, or a window. See what values are in the env that might work for you, eg name your sessions. A simpler solution, depending on your workflow, might be this [history per directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/263546/119298) plugin.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @meuh Why do I need to set HISTFILE separately for each process? That seems to complicate things only, but I'm missing what the benefit might be.

Comment: @meuh I think you misunderstood my question.

Comment: The key trick is to use PROMPT_COMMAND to store values. This is [a possible duplicate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1288/265604) and a nice [link to a solution](https://www.shellhacks.com/tune-command-line-history-bash/)

Comment: @isaac Not a duplicate, I *explicitly* don't want `histappend`.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/530/265604) or [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/212908) will help you. Managing the long list of files is another issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In zsh, use `fc -AI` to save your history, not `fc -W`. Use `-A`, not `-W`, otherwise the history from other shell instances is overwritten. And `-I` saves only the new history entries since the last save.

Given your workflow, rather than saving manually, you should probably save the history automatically. Turn on the `inc_append_history` option to save each command to the history file immediately before it gets executed.

While it's possible to achieve the same effect in bash, properly sharing history between bash instances is harder. See [Preserve bash history in multiple terminal windows](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1288/preserve-bash-history-in-multiple-terminal-windows)

Comment: Thank you! I haven't tested yet, but this looks like a lifesaver! I don't want to use `inc_append_history`, since it mixes different histories together.

Comment: Sorry, but **who** is downvoting this answer? It is the perfect answer, the only one actually answering my question...

Answer (score 2):

You can save your `bash` history with this command (I am not familiar with `zsh`):

```
history -a
```

This seems to work with `zsh`:

```
fc -ln 1 -1 > ~/.zsh_history
```

Comment: That seems to do the trick. Probably I will just call `bash` within `zsh` and then invoke `history -a`.

Comment: @pfnuesel I don't think that will work but maybe I misunderstand what you have in mind. Why call bash from zsh? Would you execute the command manually or do you want it automated?

Comment: You are right, that won't work, obviously `bash` and `zsh` have different histories. Automatising the process would be nice to have, but is not absolutely necessary.

Comment: @pfnuesel Maybe it helps to set an `EXIT` trap with this command. In addition you could set a trap for `SIGUSR1` and create a cron job which sends this signal to the shell.

Comment: That's an excellent idea for catching the history when the server is turned off. However, I first need a solution to grab the `zsh` history, since this is the shell I'm usually working with. I guess a combination of `fc` commands will do the trick, but it is not yet clear to me how.

Comment: @pfnuesel See my edit. The funny part is that this was the first version of my answer for bash before I happened to notice the `bash history` command... So for once bash is better that zsh... You can use the same command for both shells.

Comment: The zsh command you propose doesn't do what it should do: it replaces the history file with the history from that shell instance, which wipes out what other instances have written. The bash command kind of works, but it's substandard because it appends the complete history from that shell instance, which duplicates lines that were already present the last time you ran it.

Comment: @HaukeLaging Thanks for your help. I went with Gilles answer in the end, since `fc -AI` does exactly what I need. Your answer could be modified as well, I guess, to retain the history.